# docker-compose up error without information

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Good morning everyone,

I have an issue each time I'm launching the command `docker-compose up`.
At the very beginning, there are two red lines telling:

```
⠿ api Error
⠿ worker Error
```

api and worker are the names of my two containers.
What is weird is that there is no any problem during the whole installation of my containers. Everything is working fine. So I'm wondering if someone already experienced something like that because I didn't find anything on this topic.

Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${REDIS_PORT}:6379"
    container_name: container_redis

  worker:
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/
      - ./worker:/app2/
    build:
      dockerfile: ./worker/Dockerfile
    image: image_worker
    container_name: container_worker
    depends_on:
      - redis

  api:
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    build:
      dockerfile: ./api/Dockerfile
    image: image_api
    container_name: container_api
    ports:
      - "${API_PORT}:8050"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - worker
```

Here is the worker Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

RUN export http_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" \ 
&& export https_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" \
&& pacman-db-upgrade \
&& pacman -Syyu --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python-pip --noconfirm \
&& pip install requests \
&& pip install redis

WORKDIR /app

CMD python /app2/worker.py
```

And this is the api Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux:latest

COPY api/requirements.txt ./

RUN export http_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" \ 
&& export https_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" \
&& pacman-db-upgrade \
&& pacman -Syyu --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python --noconfirm \
&& pacman -S python-pip --noconfirm \
&& pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app

CMD chmod a+x entrypoint.sh && ./entrypoint.sh
```

Please find the result of the `docker-compose up command`:

```
[david@user_01 project]$ docker-compose up
[+] Running 0/2
 ⠿ api Error                                                                                                                           1.7s
 ⠿ worker Error                                                                                                                       1.6s
Sending build context to Docker daemon  174.3MB
Step 1/4 : FROM archlinux:latest
latest: Pulling from library/archlinux
ed520c7fd61b: Pull complete 
6a1d554dffe9: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:5b8fd376c75d2480080201961c71c33af621632cb5840d67214a5aff8f05577b
Status: Downloaded newer image for archlinux:latest
 ---> 481b70173ad4
Step 2/4 : RUN export http_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" && export https_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" && pacman-db-upgrade && pacman -Syyu --noconfirm && pacman -S python --noconfirm && pacman -S python-pip --noconfirm && pip install requests && pip install redis
 ---> Running in 6592ca17346b
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core downloading...
 extra downloading...
 community downloading...
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (5)  Old Version  New Version  Net Change  Download Size

core/curl    7.81.0-3     7.82.0-1       0.01 MiB       1.10 MiB
core/expat   2.4.6-1      2.4.7-1        0.00 MiB       0.12 MiB
core/gpgme   1.17.0-2     1.17.1-1       0.00 MiB       0.43 MiB
core/hwdata  0.356-1      0.357-1        0.00 MiB       0.46 MiB
core/pacman  6.0.1-3      6.0.1-4        0.00 MiB       0.89 MiB

Total Download Size:    2.99 MiB
Total Installed Size:  10.13 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.02 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 curl-7.82.0-1-x86_64 downloading...
 pacman-6.0.1-4-x86_64 downloading...
 hwdata-0.357-1-any downloading...
 gpgme-1.17.1-1-x86_64 downloading...
 expat-2.4.7-1-x86_64 downloading...
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
:: Processing package changes...
upgrading curl...
upgrading expat...
upgrading gpgme...
upgrading hwdata...
upgrading pacman...
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (3)  New Version  Net Change  Download Size

core/gdbm    1.23-1         0.77 MiB       0.26 MiB
core/libnsl  2.0.0-2        0.07 MiB       0.02 MiB
core/python  3.10.2-1      53.85 MiB      11.35 MiB

Total Download Size:   11.63 MiB
Total Installed Size:  54.69 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 python-3.10.2-1-x86_64 downloading...
 gdbm-1.23-1-x86_64 downloading...
 libnsl-2.0.0-2-x86_64 downloading...
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
:: Processing package changes...
installing gdbm...
installing libnsl...
installing python...
Optional dependencies for python
    python-setuptools
    python-pip
    sqlite [installed]
    mpdecimal: for decimal
    xz: for lzma [installed]
    tk: for tkinter
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (31)                     New Version    Net Change  Download Size

extra/python-appdirs             1.4.4-6          0.07 MiB       0.01 MiB
community/python-cachecontrol    1:0.12.6-4       0.10 MiB       0.03 MiB
extra/python-cffi                1.15.0-3         1.02 MiB       0.22 MiB
extra/python-chardet             4.0.0-5          2.10 MiB       0.19 MiB
community/python-colorama        0.4.4-6          0.08 MiB       0.02 MiB
community/python-contextlib2     0.6.0.post1-6    0.05 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-cryptography        36.0.1-1         4.14 MiB       0.93 MiB
community/python-distlib         0.3.4-1          0.93 MiB       0.18 MiB
community/python-distro          1.7.0-1          0.16 MiB       0.03 MiB
community/python-html5lib        1.1-11           1.34 MiB       0.21 MiB
extra/python-idna                3.3-4            0.66 MiB       0.09 MiB
community/python-more-itertools  8.12.0-1         0.48 MiB       0.07 MiB
community/python-msgpack         1.0.3-1          0.25 MiB       0.07 MiB
extra/python-ordered-set         4.0.2-6          0.06 MiB       0.01 MiB
extra/python-packaging           20.9-7           0.18 MiB       0.05 MiB
extra/python-pep517              0.12.0-4         0.13 MiB       0.03 MiB
extra/python-ply                 3.11-10          0.31 MiB       0.08 MiB
community/python-progress        1.6-5            0.04 MiB       0.01 MiB
extra/python-pycparser           2.21-3           1.39 MiB       0.19 MiB
extra/python-pyopenssl           21.0.0-5         0.53 MiB       0.08 MiB
extra/python-pyparsing           3.0.1-1          0.93 MiB       0.16 MiB
extra/python-requests            2.27.1-1         0.45 MiB       0.09 MiB
extra/python-resolvelib          0.5.5-4          0.10 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-retrying            1.3.3-13         0.03 MiB       0.01 MiB
extra/python-setuptools          1:59.3.0-1       2.96 MiB       0.55 MiB
extra/python-six                 1.16.0-5         0.09 MiB       0.02 MiB
community/python-toml            0.10.2-7         0.14 MiB       0.03 MiB
extra/python-tomli               2.0.0-1          0.06 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-urllib3             1.26.8-1         0.70 MiB       0.18 MiB
community/python-webencodings    0.5.1-9          0.06 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-pip                 21.0-1           1.56 MiB       0.41 MiB

Total Download Size:    4.05 MiB
Total Installed Size:  21.13 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 python-cryptography-36.0.1-1-x86_64 downloading...
 python-setuptools-1:59.3.0-1-any downloading...
 python-pip-21.0-1-any downloading...
 python-cffi-1.15.0-3-x86_64 downloading...
 python-html5lib-1.1-11-any downloading...
 python-chardet-4.0.0-5-any downloading...
 python-pycparser-2.21-3-any downloading...
 python-urllib3-1.26.8-1-any downloading...
 python-distlib-0.3.4-1-any downloading...
 python-pyparsing-3.0.1-1-any downloading...
 python-requests-2.27.1-1-any downloading...
 python-idna-3.3-4-any downloading...
 python-pyopenssl-21.0.0-5-any downloading...
 python-ply-3.11-10-any downloading...
 python-more-itertools-8.12.0-1-any downloading...
 python-msgpack-1.0.3-1-x86_64 downloading...
 python-packaging-20.9-7-any downloading...
 python-toml-0.10.2-7-any downloading...
 python-pep517-0.12.0-4-any downloading...
 python-distro-1.7.0-1-any downloading...
 python-cachecontrol-1:0.12.6-4-any downloading...
 python-colorama-0.4.4-6-any downloading...
 python-resolvelib-0.5.5-4-any downloading...
 python-six-1.16.0-5-any downloading...
 python-tomli-2.0.0-1-any downloading...
 python-webencodings-0.5.1-9-any downloading...
 python-contextlib2-0.6.0.post1-6-any downloading...
 python-appdirs-1.4.4-6-any downloading...
 python-progress-1.6-5-any downloading...
 python-ordered-set-4.0.2-6-any downloading...
 python-retrying-1.3.3-13-any downloading...
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
:: Processing package changes...
installing python-appdirs...
installing python-msgpack...
installing python-urllib3...
Optional dependencies for python-urllib3
    python-pysocks: SOCKS support
    python-brotli: Brotli support
    python-pyopenssl: security support [pending]
    python-idna: security support [pending]
installing python-chardet...
installing python-idna...
installing python-requests...
Optional dependencies for python-requests
    python-pysocks: SOCKS proxy support
installing python-cachecontrol...
Optional dependencies for python-cachecontrol
    python-lockfile: for the FileCache
installing python-colorama...
installing python-contextlib2...
installing python-distlib...
installing python-more-itertools...
installing python-ordered-set...
installing python-pyparsing...
Optional dependencies for python-pyparsing
    python-railroad-diagrams: for generating Railroad Diagrams
    python-jinja: for generating Railroad Diagrams
installing python-six...
installing python-packaging...
installing python-setuptools...
installing python-distro...
installing python-webencodings...
installing python-html5lib...
Optional dependencies for python-html5lib
    python-lxml: lxml treebuilder
    python-genshi: genshi treewalker
installing python-tomli...
installing python-pep517...
installing python-progress...
installing python-retrying...
installing python-resolvelib...
installing python-toml...
installing python-ply...
installing python-pycparser...
installing python-cffi...
installing python-cryptography...
installing python-pyopenssl...
installing python-pip...
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests) (1.26.8)
Collecting redis
  Downloading redis-4.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (175 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.4 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from redis) (20.9)
Collecting deprecated>=1.2.3
  Downloading Deprecated-1.2.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting wrapt<2,>=1.10
  Downloading wrapt-1.14.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (77 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from packaging>=20.4->redis) (3.0.1)
Installing collected packages: wrapt, deprecated, redis
Successfully installed deprecated-1.2.13 redis-4.1.4 wrapt-1.14.0
Removing intermediate container 6592ca17346b
 ---> 57ddff99e2fa
Step 3/4 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in fed0f60d9466
Removing intermediate container fed0f60d9466
 ---> 1893670a96f3
Step 4/4 : CMD python /app2/worker.py
 ---> Running in 467d384c1a3e
Removing intermediate container 467d384c1a3e
 ---> 74704ef85f41
Successfully built 74704ef85f41
Successfully tagged image_worker:latest
Sending build context to Docker daemon  174.3MB
Step 1/5 : FROM archlinux:latest
 ---> 481b70173ad4
Step 2/5 : COPY api/requirements.txt ./
 ---> d99af5aa95f3
Step 3/5 : RUN export http_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" && export https_proxy="http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080" && pacman-db-upgrade && pacman -Syyu --noconfirm && pacman -S python --noconfirm && pacman -S python-pip --noconfirm && pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in baa81b5392e2
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core downloading...
 extra downloading...
 community downloading...
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (5)  Old Version  New Version  Net Change  Download Size

core/curl    7.81.0-3     7.82.0-1       0.01 MiB       1.10 MiB
core/expat   2.4.6-1      2.4.7-1        0.00 MiB       0.12 MiB
core/gpgme   1.17.0-2     1.17.1-1       0.00 MiB       0.43 MiB
core/hwdata  0.356-1      0.357-1        0.00 MiB       0.46 MiB
core/pacman  6.0.1-3      6.0.1-4        0.00 MiB       0.89 MiB

Total Download Size:    2.99 MiB
Total Installed Size:  10.13 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.02 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 curl-7.82.0-1-x86_64 downloading...
 pacman-6.0.1-4-x86_64 downloading...
 hwdata-0.357-1-any downloading...
 gpgme-1.17.1-1-x86_64 downloading...
 expat-2.4.7-1-x86_64 downloading...
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
:: Processing package changes...
upgrading curl...
upgrading expat...
upgrading gpgme...
upgrading hwdata...
upgrading pacman...
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (3)  New Version  Net Change  Download Size

core/gdbm    1.23-1         0.77 MiB       0.26 MiB
core/libnsl  2.0.0-2        0.07 MiB       0.02 MiB
core/python  3.10.2-1      53.85 MiB      11.35 MiB

Total Download Size:   11.63 MiB
Total Installed Size:  54.69 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 python-3.10.2-1-x86_64 downloading...
 gdbm-1.23-1-x86_64 downloading...
 libnsl-2.0.0-2-x86_64 downloading...
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
:: Processing package changes...
installing gdbm...
installing libnsl...
installing python...
Optional dependencies for python
    python-setuptools
    python-pip
    sqlite [installed]
    mpdecimal: for decimal
    xz: for lzma [installed]
    tk: for tkinter
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Package (31)                     New Version    Net Change  Download Size

extra/python-appdirs             1.4.4-6          0.07 MiB       0.01 MiB
community/python-cachecontrol    1:0.12.6-4       0.10 MiB       0.03 MiB
extra/python-cffi                1.15.0-3         1.02 MiB       0.22 MiB
extra/python-chardet             4.0.0-5          2.10 MiB       0.19 MiB
community/python-colorama        0.4.4-6          0.08 MiB       0.02 MiB
community/python-contextlib2     0.6.0.post1-6    0.05 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-cryptography        36.0.1-1         4.14 MiB       0.93 MiB
community/python-distlib         0.3.4-1          0.93 MiB       0.18 MiB
community/python-distro          1.7.0-1          0.16 MiB       0.03 MiB
community/python-html5lib        1.1-11           1.34 MiB       0.21 MiB
extra/python-idna                3.3-4            0.66 MiB       0.09 MiB
community/python-more-itertools  8.12.0-1         0.48 MiB       0.07 MiB
community/python-msgpack         1.0.3-1          0.25 MiB       0.07 MiB
extra/python-ordered-set         4.0.2-6          0.06 MiB       0.01 MiB
extra/python-packaging           20.9-7           0.18 MiB       0.05 MiB
extra/python-pep517              0.12.0-4         0.13 MiB       0.03 MiB
extra/python-ply                 3.11-10          0.31 MiB       0.08 MiB
community/python-progress        1.6-5            0.04 MiB       0.01 MiB
extra/python-pycparser           2.21-3           1.39 MiB       0.19 MiB
extra/python-pyopenssl           21.0.0-5         0.53 MiB       0.08 MiB
extra/python-pyparsing           3.0.1-1          0.93 MiB       0.16 MiB
extra/python-requests            2.27.1-1         0.45 MiB       0.09 MiB
extra/python-resolvelib          0.5.5-4          0.10 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-retrying            1.3.3-13         0.03 MiB       0.01 MiB
extra/python-setuptools          1:59.3.0-1       2.96 MiB       0.55 MiB
extra/python-six                 1.16.0-5         0.09 MiB       0.02 MiB
community/python-toml            0.10.2-7         0.14 MiB       0.03 MiB
extra/python-tomli               2.0.0-1          0.06 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-urllib3             1.26.8-1         0.70 MiB       0.18 MiB
community/python-webencodings    0.5.1-9          0.06 MiB       0.02 MiB
extra/python-pip                 21.0-1           1.56 MiB       0.41 MiB

Total Download Size:    4.05 MiB
Total Installed Size:  21.13 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
:: Retrieving packages...
 python-cryptography-36.0.1-1-x86_64 downloading...
 python-setuptools-1:59.3.0-1-any downloading...
 python-pip-21.0-1-any downloading...
 python-cffi-1.15.0-3-x86_64 downloading...
 python-html5lib-1.1-11-any downloading...
 python-chardet-4.0.0-5-any downloading...
 python-pycparser-2.21-3-any downloading...
 python-urllib3-1.26.8-1-any downloading...
 python-distlib-0.3.4-1-any downloading...
 python-pyparsing-3.0.1-1-any downloading...
 python-requests-2.27.1-1-any downloading...
 python-idna-3.3-4-any downloading...
 python-pyopenssl-21.0.0-5-any downloading...
 python-ply-3.11-10-any downloading...
 python-more-itertools-8.12.0-1-any downloading...
 python-msgpack-1.0.3-1-x86_64 downloading...
 python-packaging-20.9-7-any downloading...
 python-toml-0.10.2-7-any downloading...
 python-pep517-0.12.0-4-any downloading...
 python-distro-1.7.0-1-any downloading...
 python-cachecontrol-1:0.12.6-4-any downloading...
 python-colorama-0.4.4-6-any downloading...
 python-resolvelib-0.5.5-4-any downloading...
 python-six-1.16.0-5-any downloading...
 python-tomli-2.0.0-1-any downloading...
 python-webencodings-0.5.1-9-any downloading...
 python-contextlib2-0.6.0.post1-6-any downloading...
 python-appdirs-1.4.4-6-any downloading...
 python-progress-1.6-5-any downloading...
 python-ordered-set-4.0.2-6-any downloading...
 python-retrying-1.3.3-13-any downloading...
checking keyring...
checking package integrity...
loading package files...
checking for file conflicts...
:: Processing package changes...
installing python-appdirs...
installing python-msgpack...
installing python-urllib3...
Optional dependencies for python-urllib3
    python-pysocks: SOCKS support
    python-brotli: Brotli support
    python-pyopenssl: security support [pending]
    python-idna: security support [pending]
installing python-chardet...
installing python-idna...
installing python-requests...
Optional dependencies for python-requests
    python-pysocks: SOCKS proxy support
installing python-cachecontrol...
Optional dependencies for python-cachecontrol
    python-lockfile: for the FileCache
installing python-colorama...
installing python-contextlib2...
installing python-distlib...
installing python-more-itertools...
installing python-ordered-set...
installing python-pyparsing...
Optional dependencies for python-pyparsing
    python-railroad-diagrams: for generating Railroad Diagrams
    python-jinja: for generating Railroad Diagrams
installing python-six...
installing python-packaging...
installing python-setuptools...
installing python-distro...
installing python-webencodings...
installing python-html5lib...
Optional dependencies for python-html5lib
    python-lxml: lxml treebuilder
    python-genshi: genshi treewalker
installing python-tomli...
installing python-pep517...
installing python-progress...
installing python-retrying...
installing python-resolvelib...
installing python-toml...
installing python-ply...
installing python-pycparser...
installing python-cffi...
installing python-cryptography...
installing python-pyopenssl...
installing python-pip...
:: Running post-transaction hooks...
(1/1) Arming ConditionNeedsUpdate...
Collecting Flask
  Downloading Flask-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting redis
  Downloading redis-4.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (175 kB)
Collecting dash
  Downloading dash-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 MB)
Collecting pandas
  Downloading pandas-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.7 MB)
Collecting dash-bootstrap-components
  Downloading dash_bootstrap_components-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (209 kB)
Collecting docker
  Downloading docker-5.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146 kB)
Collecting dash-extensions
  Downloading dash_extensions-0.0.71-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting xlsxwriter
  Downloading XlsxWriter-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting schedule
  Downloading schedule-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting plotly>=5.0.0
  Downloading plotly-5.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27.7 MB)
Collecting dash-table==5.0.0
  Downloading dash_table-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting dash-core-components==2.0.0
  Downloading dash_core_components-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.8 kB)
Collecting flask-compress
  Downloading Flask_Compress-1.11-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 kB)
Collecting dash-html-components==2.0.0
  Downloading dash_html_components-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.1 kB)
Collecting Werkzeug>=2.0
  Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (289 kB)
Collecting click>=7.1.2
  Downloading click-8.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=3.0
  Downloading Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous>=2.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (25 kB)
Collecting tenacity>=6.2.0
  Downloading tenacity-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from plotly>=5.0.0->dash->-r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.16.0)
Collecting jsbeautifier
  Downloading jsbeautifier-1.14.0.tar.gz (73 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
    Preparing wheel metadata: started
    Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'done'
Collecting Flask-Caching
  Downloading Flask_Caching-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: more-itertools in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from dash-extensions->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (8.10.0)
Collecting websocket-client>=0.32.0
  Downloading websocket_client-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from docker->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (2.27.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet>=3.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2->docker->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.5 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2->docker->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.21.1 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2->docker->-r requirements.txt (line 6)) (1.26.8)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.21.0
  Downloading numpy-1.22.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (16.8 MB)
Collecting pytz>=2020.1
  Downloading pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
Collecting deprecated>=1.2.3
  Downloading Deprecated-1.2.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.4 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from redis->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (20.9)
Collecting wrapt<2,>=1.10
  Downloading wrapt-1.14.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (77 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from packaging>=20.4->redis->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.1)
Collecting brotli
  Downloading Brotli-1.0.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.7 MB)
Collecting editorconfig>=0.12.2
  Downloading EditorConfig-0.12.3-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: jsbeautifier
  Building wheel for jsbeautifier (PEP 517): started
  Building wheel for jsbeautifier (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for jsbeautifier: filename=jsbeautifier-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl size=91970 sha256=f6fc74fdb1ad7208734123404ca71ddf303b5e6cb84d7d0ad18398b45f0f0c93
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7yslx8gl/wheels/41/76/91/43d0eb201fc1adc727a88dbd3e7ab6c77894c453c0abac9bd7
Successfully built jsbeautifier
Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, tenacity, Flask, brotli, wrapt, plotly, flask-compress, editorconfig, dash-table, dash-html-components, dash-core-components, websocket-client, pytz, python-dateutil, numpy, jsbeautifier, Flask-Caching, deprecated, dash, xlsxwriter, schedule, redis, pandas, docker, dash-extensions, dash-bootstrap-components
Successfully installed Flask-2.0.3 Flask-Caching-1.10.1 Jinja2-3.0.3 MarkupSafe-2.1.0 Werkzeug-2.0.3 brotli-1.0.9 click-8.0.4 dash-2.2.0 dash-bootstrap-components-1.0.3 dash-core-components-2.0.0 dash-extensions-0.0.71 dash-html-components-2.0.0 dash-table-5.0.0 deprecated-1.2.13 docker-5.0.3 editorconfig-0.12.3 flask-compress-1.11 itsdangerous-2.1.1 jsbeautifier-1.14.0 numpy-1.22.3 pandas-1.4.1 plotly-5.6.0 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2021.3 redis-4.1.4 schedule-1.1.0 tenacity-8.0.1 websocket-client-1.3.1 wrapt-1.14.0 xlsxwriter-3.0.3
Removing intermediate container baa81b5392e2
 ---> b72b82d79ee3
Step 4/5 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in afd8defefe90
Removing intermediate container afd8defefe90
 ---> b234173cf04c
Step 5/5 : CMD chmod a+x entrypoint.sh && ./entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 0da9cf2a4803
Removing intermediate container 0da9cf2a4803
 ---> 017bfc242a3c
Successfully built 017bfc242a3c
Successfully tagged image_api:latest
[+] Running 4/3
 ⠿ Network project_default   Created                                                                                                 0.1s
 ⠿ Container container_redis   Created                                                                                                 0.1s
 ⠿ Container container_worker  Created                                                                                                 0.1s
 ⠿ Container container_api     Created                                                                                                 0.0s
Attaching to container_api, container_redis, container_worker
container_redis   | 1:C 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.884 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
container_redis   | 1:C 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.884 # Redis version=6.2.6, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
container_redis   | 1:C 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.884 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
container_redis   | 1:M 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.887 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
container_redis   | 1:M 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.890 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
container_redis   | 1:M 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.890 # Server initialized
container_redis   | 1:M 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.890 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
container_redis   | 1:M 11 Mar 2022 12:46:30.891 * Ready to accept connections
container_redis   | 1:M 11 Mar 2022 12:46:33.051 * DB saved on disk
container_worker exited with code 0
container_api     | Dash is running on http://0.0.0.0:8050/
container_api     | 
container_api     | Dash is running on http://0.0.0.0:8050/
container_api     | 
container_api     | Dash is running on http://0.0.0.0:8050/
container_api     | 
container_api     |  * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
container_api     |  * Environment: production
container_api     |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
container_api     |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
container_api     |  * Debug mode: on
```

Of course, xx.xx.xx.xx in the Dockerfiles is a real ip address.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  That should include artifacts like the `docker-compose.yml` file and if needed a `Dockerfile`, along with the actual error message you're getting, all in text form and not images.

Comment: "Exited with code 0" means that the main process in the container completed, successfully. The "worker" Dockerfile you show tries to run an `/app2/worker.py` script but doesn't include any `/app2` directory in the image at all; are you missing a `COPY` step?  Do you expect that worker process to stay alive?

Comment: I've created two volumes in my project:

- one shared volume between the api container (/app folder) and the host (/api folder)
- one shared volume between the worker container (/app2 folder) and the host (/worker folder)

Also, the worker container is creating a file inside the /app folder so the api container can use it after worker has created it.

That's why in the docker-compose, the volume ./api:/app/ is set twice. Once in each container.
Also, i'm not expecting the worker container to stay alive.
Thanks,

Comment: I found out that it was because I was specifying a name of image in my docker-compose file. So the docker-compose, before looking to the Dockerfile, is looking for pulling the image in the internet which doesn't exist because it's just a tag of mine. So I removed the "image: image_worker" from the docker-compose and there is no problem anymore. I'm wondering how can I add a name for my image in the docker-compose file without getting this error; Thanks

Comment: @VidaEninkio  I had the same problem as you. I opened a [Github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9820) and received some helpful feedback. Check out the submitted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pull_policy: never` to indicate that compose should not pull the image:

```
  worker:
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/
      - ./worker:/app2/
    build:
      dockerfile: ./worker/Dockerfile
    image: image_worker
    pull_policy: never
  ...
```

Instead, it should rely on the platform cached image.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#pull_policy

Related Github Issue: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9820